# Ways find every reference to a Role in Metadata

Tags: metadata, roles

my company is revamping a Role hierarchy, trying to slim it down and make more agile. The plan is to delete a bunch of Roles that are not used or are redundant. 
What is the best way to do a Metadata search and see if a role is used in any Reports, workflows, Process builders, etc. 
I did find an app on the AppExchange, but it is costly. https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009wgF7EAI
Looking for an alternatives.

Comment: This might work , its standard SF, https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_metadata_metadatacomponentdependency.htm

Comment: The best way to look for unused roles is to count the number of assigned users.

Answer (score 0):

Using Salesforce CLI in VSCode, you can retrieve metadata for Sharing rules, lightning page dynamic component filter criteria references to the role, queue sharing, report folder shares/report filter role references, list view shares, etc.

Comment: Is this not a bit too general to be of any use? The question was about identifying obsolete roles. So how would you approach this with the "Salesforce CLI in VSCode"?